# Открыть файл в Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, диаграммы, jquery-file-upload

Я передаю табличные данные из html в excel с помощью [tableExport](https://github.com/kayalshri/tableExport.jquery.plugin).
Выглядит это так:

```
doExport = function () {
  _this.$el.tableExport($.extend({}, _this.options.exportOptions, {
    type: type,     // выбранный тип экспорта
  }));
};
```

Получается файл с дефолтным именем `tableExport.xls`, который создаётся в дефолтной папке для загрузок, записывается, сохраняется и закрывается.

Понадобилось добавить после таблицы график. tableExport  для этого не предназначен. Итого вопрос - как после выполнения tableExport мне обратиться к этому файлу? Его имя остаётся дефолтным - но может добавляться порядковый номер. То есть имя я точно не буду знать. Понимаю, что есть способ как-то запомнить путь и имя файла, но куда копать?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Вы не можете с помощью JS обратиться к файлу из файловой системы пользователя. Вам нужно как то добавить ваши данные до сохранения файла. Вероятно для этого придется разбираться в коде библиотеки и возможно модифицировать ее. Думаю лучшим решением будет сохранить график в отдельном файле.